# Change size of individual ggplot2 charts in knitr pdf file

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

How can I modify the height and width of individual charts produced by ggplot2 in a knitr output pdf? In other words, not using the fig.height and fig.width in the code chunk options. I have some charts that work best at one size and others that need to be a different size.

Comment: Can you not just put the figures in different chunks?

Comment: not using fig.height/fig.width at all? Because you can add multiple values in the code chunks: `fig.height = c(3,2), fig.width = c(5,4)`

Comment: @Richard Telford I didn't know that I could use different options in different chunks. I had always just been setting the options in the first chunk...

Comment: @timfaber What do those vectors mean in relation to the rest of the code? In other words, what does `c(3,2)` and `c(5,4)` signify?

Comment: @Richard Telford, I'm having some weird issues with setting the different chuck options. If I put `opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/minimal',fig.align='cener',fig.show='hold',fig.width=12,fig.height=8)` in one chunk, it doesn't change anything until the next chunk.

Comment: I would put that in a chunk called setup, with nothing else (except perhaps library()). New chunks for everything else

Comment: `fig.height = c(3,2), fig.width = c(5,4)` in the chunk options would make the first figure 3 * 5 inches and the second 2 * 4 (didn't know you could do this).

Comment: Using vectors doesn't work if you have conditionally generated plots

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example .Rmd file to show how to do this.  It would be preferable to use a 'setup' chunk to loaded and attached namespaces, and to set options.  Each chunk can have its own set of options which will take precedence over the options set by `opts_chunk$set()`.

````
---
title: Change size of individual ggplot2 charts in knitr pdf file
output: pdf_document
---

It would be preferable to set chunk options only once, in a "setup" chunk.
Then, as needed, modify the options for each following chunk as needed.  The
chunk options `include = FALSE, cache = FALSE` are helpful for the set up chunk
so that it will be evaluated every time the file is knitted, but will not create
any lines within the intermediate or final file.

```{r setup, include = FALSE, cache = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 12, fig.height = 8)
```

The first figure will have the default size of 12 by 8 inches, although it is
scaled to to fit the pdf page.

```{r figure1}
ggplot(mpg) + aes(x = manufacturer, y = cty) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
```

This figure can be made again, but with a different size.

```{r figure2, ref.label = "figure1", fig.width = 4, fig.height = 3}
```
````

A screenshot of the output pdf:
[image]