# How to change chart size with ggplot2

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, charts, r-markdown

I currently have 1 table and 2 charts (one bar and one pie) that I want to knit on one page in R-Markdown.  However, when knitted, the pie chart moves to the second page as it doesn't fit.  I want to just make the pie chart smaller, because there's enough space for it to fit if it shrinks in size.

I've tried with ggsave(x, width, height) but I don't want to save just the file, I want to print it (I've tried to print the ggplot with the ggsave, but it doesn't change the results.  I've also looked at this answer. 
[Change size of individual ggplot2 charts in knitr pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160821/change-size-of-individual-ggplot2-charts-in-knitr-pdf-file)

However, I can't add in more chunks because I have a for loop.  I know it's not necessarily the best way to do things, but it's what I know.

I've also tried coor_fixed(ratio = .5), but it just shrinks the pie, not the chart size.

Also theme(aspect.ratio = 4/3) but it just skews the Pie Chart, not the actual size.

```
prempie <- ggplot(currentPrem, aes(x="", y = currentPrem$WrittenPremium, fill= Line)) + geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + coord_polar("y", start = 0) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("Automobile" = "navyblue", "Personal" = "red", "Commercial" = "gold", "Farm" = "darkgreen"))  + ggtitle(paste0(currentProvince, " Year to Date Written Premium History")) + theme_void()
     print(prempie)
```

Wanting the Pie Chart to fit on the previous page by making it smaller, but unable to do so.

Comment: If you don't want to save the plot as png to the correct size and then embed the png in your file the only possibility is to use `fig.height = 5, fig.width = 8` in code chunk.

Comment: but if I have a chunk that encases the for loop, with 2 different charts that I want different sizes, can I make chunks inside chunks or will my 2 different charts have to be the same size?

Comment: They will have to be the same size because you cannot change fig.width of the current chunk from within this chunk. Using `opts_chunk$set(fig.width=8)`) will change the width of to the next chunk you open...

Comment: If this is only about two figures just drop the loop...

Comment: I need the loop because I print the same 2 charts with all the different states. but thanks, I'll just make my charts the same size.